# cordova social share plugins doesn't work on my Angular2 app

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript, onsen-ui2

I'm stuck in a problem about how to use this social share plugins. [SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin)
When I'm trying to call this plugin, I got an undefined error. Here is my code.

```
window.plugins.socialsharing.share("test");
```

Then this "socialsharing" property is undefined. 
Is there anyone who has the same error?

Answer (score 0):

Do *any* plugins work for you? Because it can be caused by many things. Like: you don't wait for `deviceready` to fire before invoking the plugin, you didn't include a reference to `cordova.js` in your html file, you didn't include the plugin, you're running in a browser, etc.

Comment: Hi, Mr Verbruggen. Actually I found the reason why I cannot use this cordova plugin. It's because of that I'm using Monaca Debugger which third party cordova plugins don't work on. So I should have needed building my cordova app to use your plugin.